# Finding the cause of a tab error inside a Class

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, indentation

I was coding this simple 'Bank' program for my first exercise with classes in Python but when I run it, says:

```
tabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
line 45
if self.datos[x]['nombre'] == nombre and self.datos[x]['idnum'] == idnum and self.datos[x]['email'] == email:^
```

I understand what it means, and I took a look on my code and tried to find if there was some problem with the methods, nevertheless I couldn't understand what is causing it, I believe something about the dictionaries has something to do with it. So this is my code:

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self):
        self.datos = []

    def opciones(self):
        menu = ['1: Mostrar saldo',
                '2: Ingresar monto',
                '3: Retirar monto',
                '4: Cerrar']
        
        for option in range(len(menu)):
            print(option)

        opc_escoger = int(input('Escriba el número de la opción que desee: '))

        if opc_escoger == 1:
            self.mostrar()
        elif opc_escoger == 2:
            self.Ingresar()
        elif opc_escoger == 3:
            self.retirar()
        elif opc_escoger == 4:
            print('Saliendo...')
            exit()
        elif opc_escoger == 5:
            self.registrarse

        self.opciones()

    def registrarse(self):
        print('REGISTRO')
        nombre = input('Ingrese su nombre de usuario: ')
        idnum = input('Ingrese su número de documento de identificación: ')
        email = input('Ingrese su dirección de correo electrónico: ')
        self.datos.append({'nombre':nombre, 'idnum':idnum, 'email':email, 'monto': 0})

    def ingresar(self):
        print('INGRESAR')

        nombre = input('Ingrese su nombre de usuario: ')
        idnum = input('Ingrese su número de documento de identificación: ')
        email = input('Ingrese su dirección de correo electrónico: ')

        for x in range(len(self.datos)):
            if self.datos[x]['nombre'] == nombre and self.datos[x]['idnum'] == idnum and self.datos[x]['email'] == email:
                print('Dinero actual: ', self.datos[x]['monto'])
                monto = input('¿Cuál es el monto a ingresar?: ')
                self.datos[x]['monto':monto]
            else:
                print('Los datos ingresados no coinciden con los de un usuario registrado')
                self.registrarse()


#Here's some more code for the other methods, but are pretty similar to the 'ingresar' method
```

Comment: Turn on visible tabs and spaces in your editor, and then remove all tabs. Python treats tabs as 8 spaces, but if your editor displays tabs as say 4 spaces it will look right but work wrong if you mix tabs and spaces for indentation

Comment: Expanding Mark's comments: Specifics will very by editor, but there should be a way to choose the use of spaces rather than tabs. In my Geany editor, under Document, you can select Auto-indent, as well as telling the editor to use spaces when you press the tab key (Indent-type --> spaces), and (indent_width --> 4) Whenever I get your error (it happens), I know it's because the spacing is off within some block of the code. I then remove all  of the spacing in the suspect block and use my tab key (set to use 4 spaces per tab) to re-structure the indents in the block to fix it.

Comment: Mark, you should offer your comment as an answer so that Dan can select it as a successful answer. (I didn't feel right stealing credit for your answer, so I posted my advice as a comment as well.)